# How to select the currently indented lines in VIM

Tags: vim, selection, indentation

How I can selected the lines with the same indent?

For example:

```
if true: 
    line 1
    line 2
    ...
    line n
```

If the cursor is over `line 2`, how I can selected from `line 1` to `line n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [vim-indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037).

Comment: amazing! with this I can sort attributes in CSS, in normal mode `vii:!sort` :)